# JS countdown timer - Pause function

Tags: javascript, timer

Here's a simple countdown timer that counts from 9 down to 0. 
The countdown works fine. But what if I want to pause it mid-flow and then restart from where it was paused?
I have tried (see code below) to interrupt the countdown, save the number it was at, and then restart the function from the new number. But the countdown goes haywire, and I can't see why. Any ideas?

PS. I could cut and paste a timer from elsewhere, but I'm doing this for the learning experience. I'm sure there are better ways to code a countdown timer in JS, but it's bugging me that I can't make THIS way work and think I must be missing something obvious.

Many thanks

```js
var currentTimeInt = 10;
var minn = [];
var stop = 0;

 // stop
 function stopCounter() {
 currentTime = document.getElementById('mins').textContent; // grabs the number of minutes at moment of pause.

 stop = 1;
  }
 
 // restart
 function restart() {
 stop = 0;
 currentTimeInt = parseInt(currentTime, 10); // converts that number into an integer we can use
 document.getElementById("mins").innerHTML=currentTimeInt;
  newMinutes(); // restarts the newMinutes function with the start time currentTimeInt set to the time the counter stopped at
   }
 
function newMinutes() {
document.getElementById('mins').innerHTML= currentTimeInt; // displays the counter

for (aa = currentTimeInt-1; aa >= 0; aa--) {
minn.push(aa); // builds an array of numbers in descending order
document.getElementById('mins').innerHTML= minn[aa]; 
for (let bb=1; bb<=currentTimeInt; bb++) {
if (bb<currentTimeInt) {
    setTimeout( function timer(){
 if (stop == 0) {     // checks if "stop!" has been clicked and returns false to stop the function if that is the case
        document.getElementById('mins').innerHTML= minn[bb];
  console.log(minn[bb]);
 }
 else {return false;}
  }, bb*1000 );
 }

} 
}
console.log(currentTimeInt + " the end");

}
```

```html
<span>Minutes: </span><span id= "mins"></span>
<button onclick="newMinutes()">Go!</button>
<button onclick="stopCounter()">Stop!</button>
<button onclick="restart()">Reset!</button>
```

Comment: This a good opportunity to learn the basics of objects and object methods. Using them makes the task much simpler, and you'd have reusable code.

Comment: What's your thinking behind building an array of numbers in descending order?

Comment: @Teemu OK, I am gonna read up on that now. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @KhauriMcClain Just a way to iterate through numbers in the right order, counting down not counting up. I know, from subsequent googling, there are better ways to build a countdown timer in JS :)

Comment: That's definitely a strange way to do it, especially considering you could just decrement a single variable. I think I know the problem with your code, but before I answer, how adamant are you about using this array approach?

Comment: I'm not wedded to the array particularly. I just wanted to do this as much as possible on my own, and basically managed to do everything I wanted apart from the pause function. And having come this far, I couldn't see any reason why this way shouldn't be feasible (even if it's strange).

Answer (score 1):

You may try this as an example:

```js
var timerId;
var counter;

function start() {
  console.log('start');
  if (!counter) {
    reset();
  } else {
    loop();
  }
}

function pause() {
  console.log('pause');
  if (timerId) {
    clearInterval(timerId);
    timerId = null;
  }
}

function reset() {
  console.log('reset');
  pause();
  counter = 10;
  loop();
}

function loop() {
  timerId = setInterval(function() {
    if (0 >= counter) {
      pause();
      return;
    }
    console.log('counter', counter);
    counter--;
  }, 500);
}
```

```html
<button onclick='start();'>Start</button>
<button onclick='pause();'>Pause</button>
<button onclick='reset();'>Reset</button>
```

Comment: Thanks Arvind...This is interesting. When I commented out the console.log line it didn't work. I had no idea that anything inside console.log actually affected function of the script, I always thought it was just a tool to log things in the console! I am still a bit confused...anyway, easily overcome by displaying counter-- in a span. Thanks for sharing that code....interesting and helpful!

Comment: @TC, well `console.log` had an important statement i.e. `counter--`, I had moved it below log, so now things will work without logs as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my little Countdown with START, PAUSE, RESUME, STOP & RESET features:

```js
var jqcd_start_id = 'input#jqcd_start';
var jqcd_time_id = 'input#jqcd_time';
var jqcd_count_id = 'span#jqcd_count';
var jqcd_end_message = 'Time is up!';

var jqcd_countdown = '';
var jqcd_status = 'stopped';
var jqcd_current = '';
function jqcd(action){
  
  if (action == 'start') {
    if (jqcd_status == 'stopped') {
      jqcd_updtv(jqcd_start_id, 'Pause');
      jqcd_status = 'running';
      jqcd_current = jqcd_countdown;
      jqcd_updtt(jqcd_count_id, jqcd_countdown);
    }
    else if (jqcd_status == 'running') {
      jqcd_updtv(jqcd_start_id, 'Resume');
      jqcd_status = 'paused';
    }
    else if (jqcd_status == 'paused') {
      jqcd_updtv(jqcd_start_id, 'Pause');
      jqcd_status = 'running';
    }
  }
  else if (action == 'stop') {
    jqcd_updtv(jqcd_start_id, 'Start');
    jqcd_status = 'stopped';
    jqcd_updtt(jqcd_count_id, jqcd_end_message);
  }
  else if (action == 'reset') {
    jqcd_updtv(jqcd_start_id, 'Start');
    jqcd_status = 'stopped';
    jqcd_updtt(jqcd_count_id, jqcd_countdown);
  }
  
  var a =  jqcd_current.split(":");
  var m = a[0];
  var s = (a[1] - 1);
  
  if (s < 0) {
    if (parseInt(m) == 0) {
      jqcd_updtv(jqcd_start_id, 'Start');
      jqcd_status = 'stopped';
      jqcd_updtt(jqcd_count_id, jqcd_end_message);
    }
    else {
      m = m - 1;
      s = 59;
    }
  }
  
  if(s >= 0){
    setTimeout(function(){
      if (jqcd_status == 'running') {
        m = (parseInt(m) < 10)? "0" + parseInt(m): m;
        s = (parseInt(s) < 10)? "0" + parseInt(s): s;
        jqcd_updtt(jqcd_count_id, m + ":" + s);
        jqcd_current = m + ":" + s;
        jqcd('');
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
}

function jqcd_updtv(selector, value) {
  if (selector != '') {
    $(selector).val(value);
  }
}
function jqcd_updtt(selector, value) {
  if (selector != '') {
    $(selector).text(value);
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  jqcd_countdown = $(jqcd_time_id).val();
  jqcd_updtt(jqcd_count_id, jqcd_countdown);
  
  $(jqcd_time_id).keyup(function() {
    jqcd_countdown = $(jqcd_time_id).val();
    jqcd_updtt(jqcd_count_id, jqcd_countdown);
    jqcd_updtv(jqcd_start_id, 'Start');
    jqcd_status = 'stopped';
  });
});
```

```css
span#jqcd_count {
  font-size: 20pt;
  font-weight: bold;
}
input#jqcd_start,
input#jqcd_stop,
input#jqcd_reset {
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-weight: bold;
}
input#jqcd_start,
input#jqcd_stop,
input#jqcd_reset {
  width: 100px;
}
span#jqcd_count {
  font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, "Courier New", Courier, monospace !IMPORTANT;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="jqcd_count">00:30</span><br><br>
<input type="button" id="jqcd_start" value="Start" onClick="jqcd('start')" />
<input type="button" id="jqcd_stop" value="Stop" onClick="jqcd('stop')" />
<input type="button" id="jqcd_reset" value="Reset" onClick="jqcd('reset')" /><br><br>
<input type="text" id="jqcd_time" value="00:10" />
<br><br>
```

It is pretty simple to customize. The first four variables in the JavaScript code can be adapted to work with your specific HTML.

If you want an action to take place every second, add your lines of code inside of the "jqcd_updtt" function.

The CSS is completely optional, of course.

The Countdown start time is set dynamically by altering the value in the "jqcd_time" field. If, however, you want to set a static value for the Countdown starting point, you can alter the variables inside the "$(document).ready(function() {" function at the end of the JavaScript code.

PS.
This Countdown has no maximum limit for minutes or seconds

Answer (score 1):

What about keeping it KISS!

```js
let i = 9,j
function chrono(){
  if (i>=0){
    now.innerText = i--
  }
}
```

```html
<h1><div id="now">⏰ Ready!</div>
<button onclick="setInterval(function(){ chrono() }, 1000);this.style.display='none'">Start</button>
<button onclick="i=10">Reset</button>
<button onclick="j=i;i=-1">Pause</button>
<button onclick="i=j">Continue</button>
```

This is the most basic example ready to be expanded, mostly there is no `clearInterval`.

> The KISS principle states that most systems work best if they are kept
> simple rather than made complicated; therefore simplicity should be a
> key goal in design and unnecessary complexity should be avoided.
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle

Therefore, js incrementation and setInterval seems easy but they hide complex things.

An other approach using `date.now()` that provide an accurate unix timestamp based on the system clock, and the web audio api for beeping.

```js
i = Date.now();j=i+10000;z.innerText="Target @"+j
function d(){ 
    if(now.innerText < j){
        now.innerText = Date.now()
        k(3,603,80)
        }
    if(now.innerText > j){
        now.innerHTML = "<b>TIME TRAVEL COMPLETE!</b>"
        k(8,728,100)
        }        
  }

setInterval(function(){ d() }, 100)

a=new AudioContext()
function k(w,x,y){
  v=a.createOscillator()
  u=a.createGain()
  v.connect(u)
  v.frequency.value=x
  v.type="square"
  u.connect(a.destination)
  u.gain.value=w*0.01
  v.start(a.currentTime)
  v.stop(a.currentTime+y*0.001)
}
```

```html
EPOCH: <out id="now"></out><h6 id="z">
```

Answer (score 0):

The first issue here is that `currentTime` isn't globally defined, so it can't be accessed from within `restart`. Just put `var currentTime;` at the start of your file.

But you have another serious breaking issue in that you're using `setTimeout` in a really awkward way. You're creating multiple timeouts all at once and giving them a delay based on their relation to`currentTimeInt`. This has two problems. For one the use of two for loops isn't very efficient and also seems redundant as your inner for loop is just going to count up to the currentTimeInt anyway.

Secondly, you never clear (and probably won't be able to clear) the timeouts. That means when you restart your timer after pausing if any timeouts hadn't yet been fired, then your program will run those and make the minutes jump back and forth between the old timeouts and the new ones you create after unpausing.

I know in your comment you said you wanted to get this to work because you basically did the whole thing yourself, but it may not be worth continuing down this road. After looking at it some I think fixing your program would require it to be restructured, or else require it to be hacked in a way that makes it pretty inefficient. And if you're someone who's just learning Javascript, it's probably better to just start over and do it the right way anyway.

Below is an example of a better way using `setInterval` rather than `setTimeout`, but feel free to just try and figure it out on your own.

(There are ways you can improve the functionality of the code below, but it should be enough to get you the general idea)

```js
var startTimeInt = 10;
var currentTimeInt = startTimeInt;
var interval = undefined;

// start the timer
function startCounter() {
  if(!interval){
    document.getElementById('mins').innerHTML = currentTimeInt; 
    interval = setInterval(newNumber, 1000) // set an interval
  }
}

// stop
function stopCounter() {
  // clear the interval
  clearInterval(interval)
  interval = undefined;
}

// reset the timer
function resetCounter(){
  currentTimeInt = startTimeInt;
  document.getElementById('mins').innerHTML = currentTimeInt;
  //stopCounter(); startCounter();
}

// change the time and handle end of time event
function newNumber(){
  currentTimeInt--; // decrement the current time
  document.getElementById('mins').innerHTML = currentTimeInt; 
  if(currentTimeInt == 0){
    console.log("Done");
    stopCounter();
  }
}
```

```html
<span>Minutes: </span><span id= "mins"></span>
<button onclick="startCounter()">Go!</button>
<button onclick="stopCounter()">Stop!</button>
<button onclick="resetCounter()">Reset!</button>
```

Comment: Yeah I was starting to wonder if there was just no way to clear those timeouts. Never mind...I had a pretty good crack at the challenge, which was from Free Code Camp, and I met all the "user story" criteria. The pause thing was just a bonus. Now I'll go through the code you wrote and play with it until I understand it. Thanks for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working Snippet..

```js
var paused = false;
var started = false;
var stopped = true;
var currentCount = 0;
var running = false;
interval = 1000;
maxCount = 10; 

function start() {
  if (stopped){
    started = true;
    paused= false;
    stopped = false;
    currentCount = maxCount;
    loop(); running = true; 
    return; 
  }
    paused= false;
}

function pause() {
  paused= true;
}
function stop(){
 paused = false;
 started = false;
 stopped = true;
 running = false;
 currentCount = 0;
}

function update(item){
  document.getElementById("status").innerHTML  = item; 
  //console.log(item);
  --currentCount;
  if(currentCount < 0){stop()}
}

function reset() {
  currentCount = maxCount;
  document.getElementById("status").innerHTML  = currentCount; 
}

function loop(){
  if (!stopped){
    if (!paused){update(currentCount);}
    setTimeout(function(){loop()}, interval)
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick='start();'>Start</button>
<button onclick='pause();'>Pause</button>
<button onclick='reset();'>Reset</button>
<button onclick='stop();'>Stop</button>
<div id="status"></div>
```

Comment: this example uses recursion, i.e a function calling itself. and simply manages the the different states and acts accordingly

Answer (score 0):

for anyone who want to re-use the code, simply change the value of timer and the render function to fit your project

```js
var timer= 10;
var intervalID
// pause/stop
function stopTimer() {
  clearInterval(intervalID);
  intervalID= null;
}
 
// restart
function restart() {
   stopTimer();
   timer= 10;
   render();
   // Go(); //Optional
}

// start/resume
function Go() {
  if(intervalID){
    //if interval already created previously, exit function
    return
  }

  intervalID = setInterval(
    () => {
      if(timer< 1){
        //escape from interval so that counter dont go below 0
        return stopTimer();
      }

      timer--;
      render();
    }, 1000); //1000 milisecond == 1 second
}

function render(){ 
   // it is ok to run render redundantly as it does not mutate the data
   // feel free to change this to fit your needs
   console.log(timer);
   document.getElementById("mins").innerHTML=timer; 
}

render() //render once on load
```

```html
<span>Minutes: </span><span id= "mins"></span>
<button onclick="Go()">Go!</button>
<button onclick="stopTimer()">Stop!</button>
<button onclick="restart()">Reset!</button>
```